# phpunit, Travis-CI, and Symfony2 - Passes locally but fails on Travis

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, travis-ci

I have a Symfony2 (2.6) installation, and have it running phpunit on commit through Travis CI. Currently, I only have a single test. It simply verifies the presence of text on the main page. However, it suddenly started failing on Travis after passing for awhile, and I have no idea why.

When I run phpunit locally and basically anywhere but Travis, it passes.

The Travis results: https://travis-ci.org/etherealpost/etherealpost.com
Example failure: https://travis-ci.org/etherealpost/etherealpost.com/jobs/46139220

```
PHPUnit 4.4.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.
Configuration read from /home/travis/build/etherealpost/etherealpost.com/phpunit.xml.dist
Starting test 'EtherealPost\WebsiteBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testIndex'.
F
Time: 3.7 seconds, Memory: 78.00Mb
There was 1 failure:
1) EtherealPost\WebsiteBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testIndex
Failed asserting that false is true.
/home/travis/build/etherealpost/etherealpost.com/src/EtherealPost/WebsiteBundle/Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php:15

FAILURES!                            
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
The command "phpunit -v --debug" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

The .travis.yml file:

```
language: php

php:
  - hhvm
  - 5.5
  - 5.6

services:
  - mongodb

matrix:
    allow_failures:
        - php: hhvm
        - php: 5.6

before_script:
  - phpenv config-add mongo.ini
  - composer install -n --no-interaction
  - cp app/config/parameters.yml.dist app/config/parameters.yml
  - php bin/console assets:install web --symlink
  - php bin/console assetic:dump

script: phpunit -v --debug
```

And the test itself:

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $client = static::createClient();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');

    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Ethereal Post")')->count() > 0);
}
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

EDIT: Branching and doing a var_dump on $crawlwer gives the following result:

https://travis-ci.org/etherealpost/etherealpost.com/jobs/46141870

```
Starting test 'EtherealPost\WebsiteBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testIndex'.
Fclass Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler#1451 (4) {
  protected $uri =>
  string(17) "http://localhost/"
  private $defaultNamespacePrefix =>
  string(7) "default"
  private $namespaces =>
  array(0) {
  }
  private $storage =>
  array(1) {
    '0000000031ea54cc000000004ace6b3f' =>
    array(2) {
      'obj' =>
      class DOMElement#1197 (17) {
        ...
      }
      'inf' =>
      NULL
    }
  }
}
Time: 2.98 seconds, Memory: 77.75Mb
There was 1 failure:
1) EtherealPost\WebsiteBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testIndex
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Comment: What if you check the actual contents of the crawled page?

Comment: @zerkms I branched and did a var_dump on $crawler, which gives the following result: https://travis-ci.org/etherealpost/etherealpost.com/jobs/46141870

I'm not sure if Travis is truncating this at all.

Comment: it's not helpful. Provide the actual content the `filter` is running against.

Comment: @zerkms Maybe I'm not fully understanding your request. The actual content of the page that it SHOULD be receiving can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Seputaes/7789960c6d8158c34112 | That is the output that is received when I run phpunit locally or on a server I control. If you're asking what the var_dump of the filter looks like, it can be found here: https://travis-ci.org/etherealpost/etherealpost.com/jobs/46143081

Comment: "it SHOULD be receiving" --- then the test SHOULD be passing. Issue solved.

Comment: @zerkms Wouldn't have asked the question if I knew how to go about debugging this to arrive at the solution. Anywho, switched the Travis command that is run to "php web/app.php" to get the raw output of the application. It, returns the page's HTML: https://travis-ci.org/etherealpost/etherealpost.com/jobs/46145088 | So the reason for posting on SO, is because I do not know why phpunit is failing on Travis, when as far as I can tell, the output generated should match. It obviously doesn't, for a reason I do not know. Is it a phpunit issue? Is it a travis configuration issue? I don't know.

Comment: if you take that exact output, feed it to crawler and run the test without performing a real request - will it succeed? "I don't know" --- so find it out! Simplify your environment as much as it necessary to create a minimum viable and self reproducible test case that fails there and works fine locally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ultimately found the issue. In order to solve it, specifically for Symfony2/Travis, I had to do  `var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());` in the test and let Travis rerun to determine exactly what the test was seeing.

It looks like Symfony2 was running in Dev mode by default (to be expected) and was showing a few warnings that were suppressed in Production Mode, which was running locally.